# Error while compiling Ethos framework

Tags: plugins, frameworks, gtk, automake

I'm trying make Ethos framework on Mac OS Lion.
git://git.dronelabs.com/ethos

Here result of ./configure:

```
Ethos 0.2.3 
  Prefix...................:  /usr/local
  Debug level..............:  minimum
  Maintainer Compiler flags:  no
  Build API reference......:  no
  Enable test suite........:  yes
Bindings
  GObject Introspection....:  no
  Vala Bindings............:  no
  Python Bindings..........:  no
  Javascript Bindings......:  no
Now type `make' to compile ethos
```

Then I do sudo make, and while compiling arise an error:

```
Making all in c-plugins
CC    libsample.so
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_ethos_plugin_get_type", referenced from:
   _my_plugin_get_type in cc3gPLKS.o
   _my_plugin_class_init in cc3gPLKS.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [libsample.so] Error 1
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that Ethos can be installed on Mac OS X 10.7 after the following modifications:

1)Edit file: ethos_dir/ethos/ethos_manager.c  (:194):

FROM:

```
while (NULL != (filename = g_dir_read_name (dir))) {
  if (g_str_has_suffix (filename, "." G_MODULE_SUFFIX)) {
    abspath = g_build_filename (loaders_dir, filename, NULL);
    loader = ethos_manager_create_plugin_loader (manager, abspath);
    if (loader != NULL)
       loaders = g_list_prepend (loaders, loader);
    g_free (abspath);
  }
}
```

TO:

```
while (NULL != (filename = g_dir_read_name (dir))) {
#ifdef __APPLE__
   gchar* suffix = "dylib"; // to able find ethos-plugin-loader
#else
   gchar* suffix = ("." G_MODULE_SUFFIX);
#endif
   if (g_str_has_suffix (filename, suffix)) {
     abspath = g_build_filename (loaders_dir, filename, NULL);
     loader = ethos_manager_create_plugin_loader (manager, abspath);
     if (loader != NULL)
       loaders = g_list_prepend (loaders, loader);
     g_free (abspath);
   }
}
```

2)Disable making for: ethos-dir/tests, 
Change in Makefile.am

FROM:

```
line#: contents 
02: SUBDIRS = c-plugins manager-dep
30: manager_sources = manager.c
31: plugin_info_sources = plugin-info.c
```

TO:

```
02: #SUBDIRS = c-plugins manager-dep
30: #manager_sources = manager.c
31: #plugin_info_sources = plugin-info.c
```

This is necessary because, while making process it cannot find  libethos.